# R: Find minimum/maximum in dataframe and the matching column-name

Tags: r

I got a data frame. It contains 25 names of Scientist in the had of the column and the column contain 4 numbers. MAX,MIN,SD, and MEAN.

```
onebigdata <- mapply( rbind, round(mean, digits = 1), round(sd, digits = 1), max, min)
rownames(onebigdata) <- c("mean","sd","max","min")
```

Maybe this can help a bit.

Now i would like to find which variable has the highest mean and which has the highest sd.

```
apply(onebigdata, 1, max)
```

This apply function just gives me the maximum of mean,sd,min,max. But ideally i'd like the name of the scientist and the maximum.

Comment: Try with `which.max`

Comment: it just gives me 3.

Comment: Okay, if it gives you 3, use that as index to get the scientist name.  Anyway, you didn't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: i know but i dont know how to describe it. it is a dataset of 250000 numbers.

Comment: Here, usually posters show 10-15 lines of data.

Comment: I'm sorry i made a mistake now your solution works. Sorry I'm a beginner.